# nginx behaved differently for different version

Tags: nginx

I have used docker image `nginx:1.18.0-alpine` previously

and below is the conf. It works as expected

`app.localhost` --> points to the block wit `server_name app.*`

`localhost` --> points to the other block

irrepective of their order

```
upstream webapp {
    server webapp:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name app.*;

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/app.access.log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/app.error.log;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        # https://serverfault.com/a/993559
        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
        proxy_send_timeout 1800;
        send_timeout 1800;
    }
}

server {
   listen 80;

   #access_log /var/log/nginx/normal.access.log;
   #error_log /var/log/nginx/normal.error.log;

    #server_name unicornpost.com;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```

where as `nginx/1.23.4` with the same above configuration

`localhost` or `app.localhost` always points to the first server block irrepective of `server_name app.*` or `no server_name`
`

Comment: Are there any other `server` blocks in your configuration? Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.